# I don't know the meaning of 'Has no student used this previously?'

Tags: meaning

'Has no student used this previously?'

What is the exact meaning of the sentence above?

Maybe, I think the meaning of the sentence is 'I think that no one has used this previously.'
Am I right? If not, could you tell me the exact meaning of the sentence?

Comment: The statement version is "No student has used this previously."  Does that help you understand the meaning of the question?

Comment: Yes, you are correct and stangdon is more precise.

Comment: But it could be paraphrased "I think a student may have used this previously. Am I wrong?"

Comment: Yes, that question can be asked in an incredulous tone, in which case it would be similar to "Hasn't a student used this previously?".

Answer (score 1):

The exact, pedantic meaning is pretty much as you suggest - the questioner is asking if zero students have used this in the past.

Idiomatically, the questioner is probably expressing surprise that 'this' - presumably a tool or resource - has not been used in the past by any student, with perhaps the implication that this resource is obvious, and/or there's some major disadvantage that the questioner has not noticed yet.